# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Data source org.apache.spark.sql.redis does not support streamed reading

Tags: java, apache-spark, redis

Trying to read data from Redis with spark 2.3(java) code.
Able to read the non-streaming data from Redis, **but unable to read data in case of streamed reading from Redis**, I get the following errors:
1) when I specify the format as :

```
Dataset<Row> RedisData = spark.readStream()
                          .format("org.apache.spark.sql.redis")
                          .option("stream.keys","carsstream")
                          .schema(UserSchema5)
                          .load();
```

The error is :

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Data source org.apache.spark.sql.redis does not support streamed reading
```

2) when I specify the format as :

```
Dataset<Row> RedisData = spark.readStream()
                              .format("redis")
                              .option("stream.keys","carsstream")
                              .schema(UserSchema5)
                              .load();
```

The error is

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: redis. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
```

I have specified jars of `Jedis(version 3.1.0)`, `spark-redis(2.3.1)`, `spark-core_2.11(version 2.3.0)`.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Please edit the question for easy understanding

Answer (score 0):

Based on the errors you are facing, and the code you are trying to implement, I have deduced that you are using **Spark Structured Streaming**. Please refer to the snippets below for your reference. Also, I have shared link to my GitHub repository where you can find the complete code.

You are required to create a `DataFrame/Dataset` and not `Streaming DataFrame/Dataset`.
Therefore, you have to do something like this:

```
val keysPattern = s"${topic}:*"

// SCHEMA FOR STATE DATA CACHED IN REDIS DATA
val redisSchema = StructType(
        List(
            StructField("col1",StringType,true),
            StructField("col2",StringType,true),
            StructField("col3",StringType,true)
        )
    )
val redisDf = spark.read
                    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.redis")
                    .schema(redisSchema)
                    .option("keys.pattern", keysPattern)
                    .load
```

You join this `dataframe` with `Streaming DataFrame` like this:

```
// JOIN THE STREAMING DATA WITH REGULAR DATAFRAME
val joinedDf = streamingDf.joinWith(
                      redisDf,
                      trim(col("col1")) === trim(col("u_id")),
                      "left"
                    ).select("_1.*", "_2.*")
```

The join of a `regular DataFrame` and `Streaming DataFrame` results in `Streaming DataFrame`. To write the `Streaming DataFrame` back to Redis, you would need to implement a `foreach writer` as well. This looks something like this:

```
// REDIS CONNECTOR - FOREACHWRITER SINK
val redisForeachWriter : RedisForeachWriter = new RedisForeachWriter("localhost","6379", topic)

// PUSH NEW USER DETAILS TO REDIS FOR STATE REFERENCE
val redisSinkQuery = joinedDf
             .select(
                 "col1", "col2", ... , "coln"
             )
             .writeStream
             .outputMode("update")
             .foreach(redisForeachWriter)
             .start
```

A sample **RedisForeachWriter** looks like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.ForeachWriter
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.collection.JavaConversions
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset

class RedisForeachWriter(val host: String, port: String, val topic: String) extends ForeachWriter[Row]{
    // val host: String = p_host
    // val port: String = p_port

    var jedis: Jedis = _

    def connect() = {
        jedis = new Jedis(host, port.toInt)
    }

    override def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = {
        return true
    }

    override def process(record: Row) = {
        val u_id = record.getString(1);

        if( !(u_id == null || u_id.isEmpty())){
          val columns : Array[String] = record.schema.fieldNames

          if(jedis == null){
              connect()
          }

          for(i <- 0 until columns.length){
            if(! ((record.getString(i) == null) || (record.getString(i).isEmpty()) || record.getString(i) == "") )
              jedis.hset(s"${topic}:" + u_id, columns(i), record.getString(i))
          }
        }
    }

    override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable) = {

    }
}
```

You can refer to my [Github](https://github.com/krohit-scala/MSStreamingStack) with a similar use-case for your reference and revert for clarification. https://github.com/krohit-scala/MSStreamingStack

**EDIT**: Do add these dependency in your application POM.

```
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.redislabs</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-redis</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I am still getting an error in the java version of this part of code where format is specified : val redisDf = spark.read
                    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.redis") 
                    .schema(redisSchema)
                    .option("keys.pattern", keysPattern)
                    .load                                                                                                           The Error  get is : "  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Data source org.apache.spark.sql.redis does not support streamed reading  "

Comment: I have added the `POM dependancy`, the Spark-Redis dependency is very version specific. Be sure that you are using this version (*specified in the answer*) only.

Comment: I tried with those dependency versions as specified, but still getting the error with that format part : ERROR IS :  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Data source org.apache.spark.sql.redis does not support streamed reading.                            I previously tried reading non-streaming data from redis using the same format and that worked fine. But not sure why it does not work in case of streaming data.

Comment: Share your minimum possible code via GitHub along with some sample input format. I'll pick it up from GitHub itself and probe.

Comment: I have added the code and the way I have created my redis input stream. https://github.com/SuryaprakashM/spark-redis.git

Comment: HI Surya, had a long day yesterday. I'll try to give it a shot today, will share the updates.

Comment: Okay Rohit...Thank You.

Comment: Hi Rohit, just wanted to know if there are any suggestions from you regarding that issue.

Comment: Hi @SuryaPrakashM, a few days ago, I executed your changes in my job and it run fine for me. Can you share your complete project structure (with POM and all) via GitHub. You can choose to hide your sensitive files and logic. That way I will try to clone your project and see if it runs.

Comment: sure..i will share it.